# Finding a path through vertices in a graph with SAT Solving in Python

Tags: python, graph, z3, sat

Essentially what I am trying to do is find a path from v1 to v2 on a graph but some nodes are coloured and we can't visit them.

I understand the constraints but the part I am really having a problem with is understanding how to add the possible moves to the constraints.

If I set up the booleans in this way

```
nodes = [Int('"n%i_%i" % (i, j)) for i in range(len(G))]

moves = []
for i in range(len(G)):
     moves += ?
```

The condition would be that the nodes are beside each other so i = i and j = j +1  (or i = i +1 and j = j) and that the node is allowed to be visited so path=True, which is a feature of the graph. So for example G[i][j] == True.

Would I use something like (or(And(nodes are beside each other), (G[i][j] == True)))
And how can I express the nodes are beside each other?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you trying to implement path finding in adjacency matrix representation?
What specifically do you mean by 'coloured' nodes?
Or are you trying to traverse a 2d-grid starting from (0,0) and moving down and right only?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So coloured means we can't visit them and the nodes do have coordinates like a 2d grid but we are not necessarily starting from (0,0). Yes we are only move in the right and down direction.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not understand what you mean with colored nodes, here would be a preliminary solution:

### Predicates

First, we define some predicates and what they intuitively mean for us:

`p(X, Y, n)` denotes that we visit the node at the coordinates X, Y at time point n, where time point starts at 0 and goes up to length of G.

`go(right, n)` denotes that we go to right at time point n.

`go(down, n)` denotes that we go down at time point n.

### Encoding

#### Initial State

Initially, we know that `p(Start_X, Start_Y, 0)` is true.
Consequently, we add the unit clause `[p(Start_X, Start_Y, 0)]`

#### Movement

At each time point, we have to move. Therefore, for every time point t, add the clauses
`[go(right, t), go(down, t)]` and `[not go(right, t), not go(down, t)]`
This is also known as the exactly once constraint, i.e. we can either move right or down.

Now, we need to relate the p predicate and the go predicate:
If p(X, Y, T) is true, and go(right, T), then p(X+1, Y, T+1) is true.
Consequently, add the clauses `[not p(X, Y, T), not go(right, T), p(X+1, Y, T+1)]`.

In a similar way you can encode the "go down" action.

#### Final State

Now, we have to ensure that we finally reach the node v2.
Please note that it is not enough to add that `p(v2_x, v2_y, t)` is true for some time point.
Instead, we have to ensure that models violating this condition are excluded:
As we can only move down or right, we know that we cannot visit nodes that are below of v2 or right to it.
Consequently, we add unit clauses of the form `[not p(X, Y, t)]`, where t is the distance from v1 and v2.

#### Auxiliary

Now, a solution can be read off from your model, but your model may looks a bit strange in the sense that multiple p-predicates are true at the same time point.
In general, this does not hurt, but can be excluded if you say so:
`[not p(X1, Y1, t),  not p(X2, Y2, t)]` for every t and distinct coordinates.